# Is it possible to change runs-on label in Github-Actions based on user input

Tags: github, github-actions, building-github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

Is there any way of changing `runs-on` value based on the user input from Github actions? Checked the resources and questions however could not find any suitable approach. Does anyone have a tip on this?

Here is the input field, if it is checked then the job will run on self-hosted instance otherwise, on Github instance.

[image]

Comment: [`inputs` context is be available under `runs-on`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#inputs-context). You can modify the input to `choice` type with values that you want to pass on. Or, alternatively, based on your custom input, you may [set the value in a separate job and use its output with `needs` context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs) to populate `runs-on`.